XAML Slider size
I'm building a C#/WPF application, and using sliders.  The sliders do not change size with their height parameter.  The slider is always against the top or left of the defined height/width.

Is there a way to make the slider fill the box, as all other controls do?  I'm specifically building a touch application, and would like a much larger touch area.
I have discovered that I can use the RenderTransform to increase the size of the slider, but it's not ideal, particularly as I want to use the sliders in a user control in a resizeable grid, where it would be really nice if the sizing was done automatically.
Very easy to reproduce in any project, just drag a slider from the toolbox onto the XAML window, and resize it.  It happens on any window, any User Control.  I've tried all the settings I can see - no effect.  Could it be a bug in a particular version of something that I'm running?
Here's the XAML...
<Grid>
    <Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,447,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" Height="85" />
</Grid>


You need to show reproducable code

If you show just your XAML (simplify it as much as you can but still reproduce the issue), you problem can be solved.

The size of Track and Thumb is hardcoded. So you need to edit the Style of Slider.

If you don't want to re template your slider then you could use viewbox to magnify the default size. Align left and top will put a control up in the top left of a grid.
